# Seamlessly loop through LED's - Shift Register

Tags: arduino-uno, led, shift-register

I am using the following code to create a snake-like affect (3 LED's wide) moving through 24 LED's using 3 shift registers:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < 27; i++){
    setRegisterPin(i, HIGH);
    writeRegisters();
    if(i >= 3){
     setRegisterPin(i-LEDLength, LOW);
     writeRegisters(); 
    } 
    delay(100);
  }//end for
```

The problem with this is that the snake has to completely end before it starts again, instead of looking like one continuous snake going in circles.

So when the three LED's get to the end I want it to immediately begin to light the beginning again. If 2 are lit at the end then 1 should be lit at the start, etc. Like this pattern:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean something like this? (untested):

```
void loop() {
  // use static or global variables to remember positions (these are initialized only once):
  static uint8_t hi_pos = 0;  // where HIGH should be set
  static uint8_t lo_pos = 21; // where LOW should be set

  setRegisterPin(hi_pos, HIGH); // turn on led in head
  setRegisterPin(lo_pos, LOW);  // turn off led in tail
  writeRegisters();             // update registers

  // ensure it won't overflow:
  if (++hi_pos == 24) hi_pos = 0;
  if (++lo_pos == 24) lo_pos = 0;

  // or:  hi_pos = (hi_pos+1) % 24;  // but divisions are slower on AVR

  delay(100);
}
```

It will go in sequence:

```
ON  OFF
 0   21
 1   22
 2   23
 3    0
 4    1
...
22   19
23   20
0    21
...
```

forever

Comment: wow, I'm not sure how you did that but it works. Can you explain the code further please?